# Python Pandas Dataframe find column index number for a list of Values

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am working on sanitizing unstructured data(loaded from an .xlsx file) that has been loaded to a dataframe and they don't have column labels instead has column index.By reading values from each column i need to arrive at the the row and the values will be used to set column label.

print(df)

```
   0   1   2    3   4    5  
o NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN  NaN
1 NaN NaN %    NaN NaN  NaN
2 Usr Id  Add  ph  dept Sec 
3 Tom 12  Addr 123 IT   F.E
```

The solution i have is below to identify the index of row,

```
for col in df.columns :
   header_idx = df[df[col].eq('Usr')].index.values[0]
```

Once index is identified i will read and load the excel source file again from header_idx onwards to a dataframe.
This solution works perfectly, but i have one more use case where i need to check in list of strings to identify the index. For example for 1st column i need to check for ["Usr","User","Usrnm"] etc. Can some one provide direction?

Comment: Try [isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) instead of eq(): `header_idx = df[df[col].isin(['Usr','User','Usrnm'])].index.to_list()[0]`.

Comment: How did you read your file for the first time?

Answer (score 0):

A more generic solution could be:

```
with pd.ExcelFile('data.xlsx') as xlsx:
    df = pd.read_excel(xlsx, header=None)
    skip = df.dropna().index[0]
    df = pd.read_excel(xlsx, skiprows=skip)
```

If you consider the header has no null values and before it, there is at least one empty cell on each row, you can use [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas-dataframe-dropna) to remove this rows. You have also a `thresh` parameter for more security.

Output:

```
>>> df
   Usr  Id   Add   ph dept  Sec
0  Tom  12  Addr  123   IT  F.E
```

[image]

Comment: I would just slice the first `df` from `skip` and assign new columns instead of reading and parsing all over again.

Comment: @QuangHoang. I'm agree with you but in this case you lost the capacity of Pandas to infer the dtype. The OP can also load the first 10 lines to discover the headers then read all file. 12 and 123 are strings in the first df but integers to the second df.